# what are django channels InMemoryChannelLayer limitations

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

i'm learning to use channels (Django channels), and i don't want to install Redis or any other tool.

- can i just use `InMemoryChannelLayer` in production ?
- what are the limitations when using `InMemoryChannelLayer` ?
- is there a way to use a Django model for saving channel layers ?

Comment: anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `InMemoryChannelLayer` has a memory leak which may not be suitable for production.
Details [here](https://github.com/django/channels/pull/863) (merged on Feb 13 2018 - part of 2.1.0 release)